# How to adjust column width in <lightning:tile> <dl class="slds-list_horizontal">?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, slds, slds-grid

I tried following the SLDS Utilities patterns for both [Name Value Pairs](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/name-value-list/) and [Description List](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/description-list/)...

In both attempts, the labels' text was truncated, and the tiles had an undesirable excess of white space.

How can I change my markup so that the label columns are sufficiently wide and space is used better?

[image: Label text is truncated despite abundant space]

```
<div class="slds-grid" >
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3"  id = "RecordDeets1">
        <lightning:tile>
            <dl class="slds-list_horizontal" >
                <dt class="slds-item_label">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">Close Date:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">{!v.vitalStatsWrapper.closeDate}</p>
                </dd>
                <dt class="slds-item_label">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">OBC Date:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">{!v.vitalStatsWrapper.obcCompletedDate}</p>
                </dd>
                <dt class="slds-item_label">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">Time Zone:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">{!v.vitalStatsWrapper.timeZone}</p>
                </dd>
                <dt class="slds-item_label">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">Cancel Request in Last 60 Days:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">{!v.vitalStatsWrapper.reqCancelLast60}</p>
                </dd>
                <dt class="slds-item_label">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">Cancel Request in Last 30 Days:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">{!v.vitalStatsWrapper.reqCancelLast30}</p>
                </dd>
            </dl>
        </lightning:tile>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3" id = "RecordDeets2" >
           <lightning:tile>
                <dl class="slds-list_horizontal" >
                <dt class="slds-item_label">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">CMRR:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">${!v.vitalStatsWrapper.cmrr}</p>
                </dd>
                <dt class="slds-item_label">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">Last Invoice Date:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">{!v.vitalStatsWrapper.lastInvoiceDate}</p>
                </dd>
                <dt class="slds-item_label">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">Bill to Account:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">${!v.vitalStatsWrapper.billToAccount}</p>
                </dd>
                <dt class="slds-item_label">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">Credit to Account:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">${!v.vitalStatsWrapper.creditToAccount}</p>
                </dd>
                <dt class="slds-item_label">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">Bill Cycle Day:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">{!v.vitalStatsWrapper.billCycleDay}</p>
                </dd>
                </dl>
        </lightning:tile>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3" id = "AppData">
        <lightning:tile label="App Data">
        <dl class="slds-list_horizontal">
                <dt class="slds-item_label">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">Last Login Date:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">{!v.vitalStatsWrapper.lastLoginDate}</p>
                </dd>
                <dt class="slds-item_label">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">Last Contact Upload Date:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">{!v.vitalStatsWrapper.lastContactUploadDate}</p>
                </dd>
                <dt class="slds-item_label">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">Total Active Contacts:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">{!v.vitalStatsWrapper.totalActiveContacts}</p>
                </dd>
                <dt class="slds-item_label">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">Total Inactive Contacts:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">{!v.vitalStatsWrapper.totalInactiveContacts}</p>
                </dd>
                <dt class="slds-item_label">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">Last Campaign Date:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">{!v.vitalStatsWrapper.lastCampaignDate}</p>
                </dd>
                <dt class="slds-item_label">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">FB Connected?:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">{!v.vitalStatsWrapper.facebookConnectedBoolean}</p>
                </dd>
                <dt class="slds-item_label">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">LinkedIn Connected?:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">{!v.vitalStatsWrapper.linkedInConnectedBoolean}</p>
                </dd>
            </dl>
        </lightning:tile>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was add style="width:200px;" to the dt and dd elements, and everything fits nicely.

[image: label columns no longer truncated]

```
<div class="slds-grid" >
    <div class="slds-col" id = "RecordDeets1">
        <lightning:tile  >
            <dl class="slds-list_horizontal slds-wrap" >
                <dt class="slds-item_label" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">Close Date:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">{!v.vitalStatsWrapper.closeDate}</p>
                </dd>
                <dt class="slds-item_label" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">OBC Date:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">{!v.vitalStatsWrapper.obcCompletedDate}</p>
                </dd>
                <dt class="slds-item_label" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">Time Zone:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">{!v.vitalStatsWrapper.timeZone}</p>
                </dd>
                <dt class="slds-item_label" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">Cancel Request in Last 60 Days:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">{!v.vitalStatsWrapper.reqCancelLast60}</p>
                </dd>
                <dt class="slds-item_label" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">Cancel Request in Last 30 Days:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">{!v.vitalStatsWrapper.reqCancelLast30}</p>
                </dd>
            </dl>
        </lightning:tile>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col" id = "RecordDeets2" >
           <lightning:tile>
                <dl class="slds-list_horizontal slds-wrap" >
                <dt class="slds-item_label" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">CMRR:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">${!v.vitalStatsWrapper.cmrr}</p>
                </dd>
                <dt class="slds-item_label" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">Last Invoice Date:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">{!v.vitalStatsWrapper.lastInvoiceDate}</p>
                </dd>
                <dt class="slds-item_label" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">Bill to Account:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">${!v.vitalStatsWrapper.billToAccount}</p>
                </dd>
                <dt class="slds-item_label" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-has-flexi-truncate">Credit to Account:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">${!v.vitalStatsWrapper.creditToAccount}</p>
                </dd>
                <dt class="slds-item_label" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">Bill Cycle Day:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">{!v.vitalStatsWrapper.billCycleDay}</p>
                </dd>
                </dl>
        </lightning:tile>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col" id = "AppData">
        <lightning:tile label="App Data">
        <dl class="slds-list_horizontal slds-wrap">
                <dt class="slds-item_label" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">Last Login Date:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">{!v.vitalStatsWrapper.lastLoginDate}</p>
                </dd>
                <dt class="slds-item_label" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">Last Contact Upload Date:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">{!v.vitalStatsWrapper.lastContactUploadDate}</p>
                </dd>
                <dt class="slds-item_label" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">Total Active Contacts:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">{!v.vitalStatsWrapper.totalActiveContacts}</p>
                </dd>
                <dt class="slds-item_label" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">Total Inactive Contacts:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">{!v.vitalStatsWrapper.totalInactiveContacts}</p>
                </dd>
                <dt class="slds-item_label" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">Last Campaign Date:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">{!v.vitalStatsWrapper.lastCampaignDate}</p>
                </dd>
                <dt class="slds-item_label" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">FB Connected?:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">{!v.vitalStatsWrapper.facebookConnectedBoolean}</p>
                </dd>
                <dt class="slds-item_label" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">LinkedIn Connected?:</p>
                </dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail" style="width: 200px;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate">{!v.vitalStatsWrapper.linkedInConnectedBoolean}</p>
                </dd>
            </dl>
        </lightning:tile>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

No matter how you look at it, you managed to avoid using the correct styles throughout your code. The Name Value pair looks like:

```
<dl class="slds-list_horizontal slds-wrap">
    <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate">
        Last Login Date:
    </dt>
    <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate">
        {!v.vitalStatsWrapper.lastLoginDate}
    </dd>
```

While the Description List looks like:

```
<dl class="slds-dl_horizontal">
    <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">
        Last Login Date:
    </dt>
    <dd class="slds-dl_horizontal__detail">
        {!v.vitalStatsWrapper.lastLoginDate}
    </dd>
    ...
```

Note the different class names, no inner paragraph block, and a lot more classes than you might have been expecting. It's important to pay attention to detail.

Comment: I initially used these "correct" styles copied from the SLDS reference and got the same result. The code I posted was the result of several iterations slightly manipulating the markup to see if I could get anything to budge.